# What is your definition of happiness?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, happiness

My primary question is your personal definition of happiness.

What I have understood so far is there is some feeling which I have felt which makes me feel happy.  This happens in different occasions, some of which I felt are :

1. **Understanding** the logic behind something.  An example was a time in school when I understood what it meant to say that a line intersected a plane at a particular point.  Instead of just solving the equation, I was able to actually feel what is going on when I did each of those calculations.
2. When I feel **some body found my work useful**. - Like a website I made etc.
3. When I travel aimlessly and **find** an exotic spot.
4. When other people say/**acknowledge** that I did something good.

But many at times, when one of the above situations happen, I dont feel that happiness.  May be I am tired / tensed at that point of time.

So I am not able to find a logic behind happiness.

What is yours?

**Old Version:**

I have felt moments of happiness in school when I have been able to figure out things I never have done.  Or when figuring out things no body else had.

I traveled a bit hoping to meet happiness, did not happen.

Have any of you been able to define happiness?

Comment: As it's currently presented, the question is a little chatty and subjective. (Many would say that a personal search for happiness is what life is about; but nevertheless it does not fit within the Q&A format of this forum.) Perhaps you could revise it to address the question of what philosophical works explicitly concern the topic of happiness, or which authors have preoccupied themselves principally with the subject of happiness as a core aim of life or for structuring society.

Comment: you should show interest and seriousness showing some prior research in the matter.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap : Thanks.  I know that would be better way to ask.  But, I really wanted each of our views about happiness, hence did not change.  I know this will get closed/deleted also.  But I hoped atleast few people could provide their one liner of what happiness is.

Comment: @RicardoBevilaqua : I have felt that minimum words and points are what makes us easily understand a question or answer.  Hence I have not posted any of my research etc.  I guess this question should have had atleast 2-3 paragraphs of what I have found so far etc.  But my whole intention was just to know what each of us felt.

Comment: @RicardoBevilaqua : I tried now.  But am not sure how my research etc helps.

Comment: The subjective aim of your question is an essential problem as far as compatibility with this forum goes. I've voted to close.

Comment: Thank you for informing.  I know that is what SE is framed around. But I dont know where else I could ask.

Comment: You might try philosophical fora on other social networks. This place is not the only game in town. (Of course, a final definitive answer is not likely either to be forthcoming or fast; simply trying different approaches to life and reflecting what makes them happy-making or not is also effective. Seeking swift and usable responses to thorny philosophical problems is not likely to give you happiness, for example...)

Comment: Please consider specifying the concern a little bit, and maybe reformulating so it isn't framed like a poll.

Comment: @JosephWeissman Issue is, if I do change or specify, I think I wont be able to ask what I want to ask. Now on, I know I should not ask questions that cannot be answered without facts, so I will direct those questions to other forums.

Comment: Well, it's about signal versus noise, right? It's not that opinion is bad -- it isn't, a lot of "good expertise" has subjective dimensions -- but it's just that questions and answers shouldn't be *mostly-opinion*. (I might suggest checking out our shiny new [about](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/about) page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you my "personal definition" of happiness, nor my opinion on the matter, since that's not really the purpose of a Q&A website.

If you're interested in the subject in general, you could take a look at the [SEP page on happiness](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/happiness/) and the [Wikipedia page on the philosophy of happiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_happiness). Also, Alain de Botton has made a [documentary on the philosophy of happiness of Epicurus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irornIAQzQY). In fact, the series itself is called "Philosophy: a Guide to Happiness", so you may perhaps be interested in the other episodes too.